# How to order friends using koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm fetching my friends using the Koala gem for Rails framework like that:

`@friends = current_user.facebook.get_connections("me", "friends?fields=id,name,picture.type(small)")`

The question is: how do I fetch my friends ordered by name, for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FQL or post process it in Ruby.

So for FQL in Koala, something like

`current_user.facebook.fql_query(my_fql_query)`

Where my_fql_query is

`SELECT uid, name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY name`